# GeoJSON - how to style features of GeometryCollection

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file with a feature as follows:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Start Date": "01-09-2015",
    "End Date": "01-09-2015"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries": [
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "name": "test",
        "coordinates": [74.86083984375, -52.94201777829492]
      },
      {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[74.86083984375, -52.94201777829492], [75.5419921875, -53.10721669189339]]
      },
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [75.5419921875, -53.10721669189339]
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

As you can see it consists of 2 points with a line joining the two points.

I want to style the 2 points with different colors but am stumped as to how to do that. At the moment I have the following ....

```
        var styleEnd = [
            new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#FF4500',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    })
                })
            })
        ];

        var styles = {
            'Point': [new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 7,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: 'black'
                        })
                    })
                })],
            'LineString': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'green',
                        width: 1
                    })
                })],
            'MultiLineString': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'green',
                        width: 1
                    })
                })],
            'MultiPolygon': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'yellow',
                        width: 1
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)'
                    })
                })],
            'Polygon': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'blue',
                        lineDash: [4],
                        width: 3
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
                    })
                })],
            'GeometryCollection': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'magenta',
                        width: 2
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'magenta'
                    }),
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 10,
                        fill: null,
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: 'magenta'
                        })
                    })
                })],
            'Circle': [new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'red',
                        width: 2
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
                    })
                })]
        };

        var styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
            if (feature.getGeometryName() === 'test') {
                return styleEnd;
            } else {
                return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
            }
        };

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'map.geojson',
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            }),
            style: styleFunction
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following style function:

```
var styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
            var geometries = feature.getGeometry().getGeometries();
            var start = geometries[0];
            var line = geometries[1];
            var end = geometries[2];

            var startStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                geometry: start,
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#32CD32'
                    })
                })
            });

            var endStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                geometry: end,
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#FF4500',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    })
                })
            });

            var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                geometry: line,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                        weight: 4
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#808080',
                        width: 4
                    })
            });

            return [startStyle, lineStyle, endStyle];

        };
```

Comment: startStyle,endStyle refers to what???..@sifa

Answer (score 0):

First, your `geojson` doesn't look good. See http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples.

Put your properties inside `properties` object. Something like:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

After that you will use:

```
var styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
    if (feature.get('some-property') === 'test') {
        return styleEnd;
    } else {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
};
```

Comment: Your solution implies I will have my object as seperate features. I thought it would be possible to have a single feature made up of 3 components - 2 points and a line joining those 2 points. It represents a boat trip. Start of the trip (point), the duration of the trip (line) and the end of the trip (point).

Hence me using a GeometryCollection in the GeoJSON. 

Is this in your experience not possible? I would then need to write special code for the selection to work since I would want the entire trip object (2 points and line) to be selected when clicking on any part of it.

Comment: It is possible - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.geom.GeometryCollection.html, I'll take a look at this and update my answer.