# Openlayers 4 multiple geometries with different styles

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to set feature geometry to multiple polygons and style them separately?

Something like this ... imagine polygons is array with 4 polygons

```
var PolygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(polygons)
});
```

or

```
new ol.geom.GeometryCollection([
    new ol.geom.Polygon(polygons[0]),
    new ol.geom.Polygon(polygons[1])
]);
```

and then

```
PolygonFeature.getGeometry()[1].setStyle(customStyle);
```

Comment: If this isn't working, I suggest you rephrase the question into "how?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a collection? It's easier if you work with several separate ones

I would do it by making the style a function. For example if you would create the features to have a style_id, you could do something like:

```
custom styles = [<insert some styles here>];
style_function = function(feature) {
        style_nr = feature.get('style_id'));
        return custom_style[style_nr];
    }

 source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(json)
      });
 layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        name: name,
        source: source,
        style: style_function});
```

**Edit**
I think the multipolygon solution can be handled in the same way. EG. [GeoJSON - how to style features of GeometryCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165303/geojson-how-to-style-features-of-geometrycollection)

Comment: No matters, it should looks like 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/SmVxE) and my intent is to represent it as one feature (for clustering) but be able to change style of each part independently.

Comment: Would this be a solution for you? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165303/geojson-how-to-style-features-of-geometrycollection